# Accessible Facebook Like Button

Tags: facebook-graph-api, accessibility, facebook-iframe

Has anyone created a custom Open Graph solution that queries the number of likes and creates an accessible button? Facebook's iFrame and XFBML solutions are both completely inaccessible via the keyboard and screen readers -- and no one seems to care.

The count is super easy to grab, it's the like URL that I'm not sure about. The anchors inside of Facebook's iFrames don't even have hrefs, so I'm currently digging through their scripts for some actionable targets.

Hit this URL with JS or in a browser and you'll get an ID and # of shares (are likes different though? better than nothing i guess): https://graph.facebook.com/http://putyourUrlhere

Any idea how to trigger a like without Facebook's provided code? It's ok if the button is only accessible with Javascript on since screen readers can use JS. Their code obviously requires it anyway. Has anyone done something like this with the Javascript SDK?

I'm trying to figure out if this is even possible, so I'd appreciate any insight!

PS -- iFrames are not inherently inaccessible. The problem is that Facebook's code inside of it is not. http://webaim.org/techniques/frames/#iframe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Facebook finally got around to making the like button keyboard accessible. Just took a while.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/

Answer (score -1):

It is not supported. Automated likes would compromise the authenticity of the Graph.

Comment: I still think you could put an HREF on those anchor links and make them keyboard accessible. Come on, now!